# Should I use "to whom" or "for whom"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

This is a statement being used as a stand-alone on a website.

> Are you someone **to whom** values are important?

or

> Are you someone **for whom** values are important?

Which of these is the correct usage of the conjunction before whom?

Comment: You might consider the difference between "Values are important **to** Tom." vs. "Values are important **for** Tom." Both are correct but the meaning in context (which you haven't provided) is different.

Comment: *To* and *for* are ***prepositions***, not conjunctions.

Answer (score 1):

There's little to no difference at all between the meanings conveyed by those two sentences when they stand alone. From what you've said about the context I don't think it matters which one is used.

If I were discussing values in relation to myself, I'd say

> "Values are important *to* me."

But if I were discussing the purpose of values, I'd say

> "Values are important *for* helping us know which decisions to make."